# Select specific info from Sqlite DB?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

In my db, I have a column for date (formatted as 3-1-2011) and a column for quantity. I want to grab the quantity for all results in the specified month up to a certain day.

Currently I'm using, the following:

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) FROM record WHERE date LIKE '"+month+"-%-"+year+"'"
```

This works to get the sum quantity from all records in that month/year. Now I'm looking at getting the sum only up to the specified day. So if day = 15, I want the sum quantity of all days in that month/year up to the 15th. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do something like this:

```
"SELECT SUM(quantity)
 FROM record
 WHERE date IS BETWEEN '"+month+"-01-"+year+"'
                   AND '"+month+"-"+end_day+"-"+year+"'"
```

As long as month and day are always stored as two digits (i.e. "03-01-2011" not "3-1-2011") this will work fine.  If your data is not in this format, it shouldn't be hard to convert.